# Regex with repeated rules

Tags: java, regex

I want to write a regular expression with repeated rules.

```
String resList = "WW200020+ww200020";
if(resList!=null && (resList.matches("^([a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9%_]*)"))){ 
    resList =resList.substring(2);  
}
```

`+` is the delimiter that can be optional. For example, it can also be like `WW200020`. I need to repeat the rule after the `+` symbol. How can I write a regular expression for repeated rules?

Please helpeme.

Comment: Split the string by the +, then loop on the result. Otherwise explain what you want to do with the regular expression eactly.

Comment: What's your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain the expected output with 1 `replaceAll` and an updated regex (note the `[+]` in the square brackets so that we do not have to escape it, and `?` quantifier making it optional, and also please note the final `+` quantifier that searches for the whole subpattern 1 or more times):

```
String resList = "WW200020+ww200020";
if(resList!=null && resList.matches("^([+]?[a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9%_]*)+")) { 
   resList =  resList.replaceAll("(?i)(?<=^|[+])[a-z]{2}([0-9%_]*)", "$1");
   System.out.println(resList); 
}
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/cy5uXE)

The regex - `(?i)(?<=^|[+])[a-z]{2}([0-9%_]*)` - matches the following:

- `(?i)` - Enforcing case-insensitive matching (the `[a-z]` will match `[A-Z]`, too)
- `(?<=^|[+])` - The look-behind making sure there is start-of-string (`^`) or a plus symbol right before...
- `[a-z]{2}` - 2 English letters
- `([0-9%_]*)` - 0 or more digits (`0-9`) or `%`, or `_`, captured into Group 1 that we reference in the replacement pattern as `$1`.

Comment: I used write as resList.substring(2); way. Can you pls explain me how you are replacing the first two character by using reg expression?

Comment: OI have added the explanation. This replacement is done "globally", repeatedly, and will effectively remove the 2 letters either at the beginning of the string, or after any `+` symbol.

Comment: it is not working when I have "String resList = "200020+HT200020". It is not even coming to IF condition. What could be the issue

Comment: I think it is safe to remove the `matches()` part from the code. See http://ideone.com/KtVDuW, or you will have to use a modified regex to allow an input with optional letters in the beginning and after plus symbol - see http://ideone.com/NgkBYs.